# What to do with tags like [cloud] and [delete]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup, meta-tags

[cloud](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud) and [delete](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete) are frequently meta-ish tags: They're just words pulled from the question, rather than the useful categories that we want tags to be.

My view is that various cloud services have virtually nothing in common, so having a tag to group them all serves no purpose.  It's better to use specific tags like [dropbox](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dropbox), for example.

Izzy thought some combinations were useful, like [cloud](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud)[printing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printing) or [cloud](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud)[backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup).  I think those combinations are potentially useful categories, but would be better represented by a single tag like [cloud-printing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud-printing).  There's not really a use case for filtering by [cloud](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cloud), since [printing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printing) and [backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup) have in common; you wouldn't even use the same cloud service for both.

What say ye?

[Chat discussion about this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28299746#28299746)

Comment: Can you argue a bit more for the deletion of [tag:delete] tag as well? A huge chunk of your question argues for the deletion of cloud tag only. Anyhow, I think that if a user wants to delete something, the word delete would always be there in an appropriate title, so that tag alone doesn't seem to serve any purpose for any kind of search.

Comment: After reading one of the guidelines noted [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/286110): "*Each tag should stand on its own: if a tag only makes sense when used in a group with other tags, something is wrong*", it now seems obvious to me that those tags don't stand on its own. They always need a tag which defines what is supposed to be deleted or what particular cloud service OP is dealing with.

Comment: @Firelord Yeah, I didn't focus on delete because, as you explain, it is so obviously useless.